# Which Daydream is set in Android Settings?

Tags: android, daydream

I want to know if our app Daydream is or not selected in Android Settings.

Can I discover that?
And how?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a little utility class to get some Daydream settings:

- Get if Daydream is enabled in the settings
- Get which Daydream is selected in settings
- (get if Daydream is possible on this device)

You can find it here: https://github.com/PieterAelse/blendle/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/piotapps/blendle/utils/DayDreamUtils.java

Hope this helps you out.